# Can you erase old addresses you've used in your GUI wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, wallet

There's old addresses in my GUI wallet that were used for sending, receiving, are over a year old, wont ever be used again and I cant see how to delete them from the GUI. Should I keep them? I don't need them anymore so I tried to figure out how to delete them from the GUI and I assumed at that point they'd be gone from my laptop, etc, forever?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the wallet files directly if you don't want to see them. On linux they are in ~/Monero/wallets/ (linux).